# Regex capture two digits Only if there are no other numbers in the string

Tags: php, regex

I want to find and capture two digits Only if there are no other numbers in the string, My inputs:

```
foo 12 ✅
foo 12 bar ✅
12 baz ✅
9 foo 12 ❌
foo 12 baz 2 ❌
12 2 ❌
```

I tried this pattern

```php
preg_match('`(?<=\d)\b\d\d\b(?=\d)`', $input);
```

But not working

https://regex101.com/r/Gsvguc/1

Comment: Can you just use `^\D*(\d\d)\D*$` and grab 1st capture group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the whole string to contain there aren't any other digits, so start at the beginning. Match non-digits, then use `\K` to reset the match (this is needed for the result to contain only the two digits you want), match the 2 digits, and lookahead for no more digits until the end of the string:

```
^\D*\K\d{2}(?=\D*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Gsvguc/2

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to fail a string with two digits separated with non-digits and then match two digits:

```php
.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lavG5u/1):

[image]

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D+                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)                    backtracking control verb that makes the regex engine
                             "skip" forward to this position on failure and tries 
                             to match again
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*F)                       fail the current match, proceed to search for a new one
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

[**PHP example**](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKzNNQaOgKDU9PjexJDlDQ71OTysmJcZFOyZFT0tDK9jbM0BTQ8tNsyYmKSal2qg2JqlOXUdBPS0/X8HQCMhSAWvT1FSoVkhNzshXUILIKNjZ2UHlog1iY/KUrBVqybQKaFhSYhU2qyAyVLTKUgG3v2ByVLQOaiDID/iCEixP3QA1whGcWK35/x8A):

```php
if (preg_match('~.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b~', 'foo 12', $match)) { echo "foo 12 >>> $match[0]\n"; }
if (preg_match('~.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b~', '12 baz', $match)) { echo "12 baz >>> $match[0]\n"; }
if (preg_match('~.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b~', '9 foo 12', $match)) { echo "9 foo 12 >>> $match[0]\n"; }
if (preg_match('~.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b~', 'foo 12 baz 2', $match)) { echo "foo 12 baz 2 >>> $match[0]\n"; }
if (preg_match('~.*\d\D+\d.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\d{2}\b~', '12 2', $match)) { echo "12 2 >>> $match[0]\n"; }
```

**Result**:

```
foo 12 >>> 12
12 baz >>> 12
```

Comment: Thanks, look like it not working for all of my inputs https://regex101.com/r/Gsvguc/3

Comment: @Mwthreex That all works fine, `\D` matches line breaks.  Check https://regex101.com/r/lavG5u/1